# How to setup Eureka naming Service instead of RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, rest, model-view-controller, netflix-eureka

I have developed 2 microservices in Spring:

- a UI-service
- a Login-service, which also has UI (html-form) for testing

The UI-service is consuming the Login-service using the below uri, now i want not to give the url but to use Eureka naming server here

UI-service (code)

```
  @RequestMapping("/log")
  public String abc(HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String uri = "http://localhost:8093/accounts/login"; 
       // want to use Eureka discovery instead of directly consuming this service.

         RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
         String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);

         return result;
        //request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_LOGIN");
   }
```

Comment: Have you even taken some time to read the documentation [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#__enablediscoveryclient) and [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_spring_resttemplate_as_a_load_balancer_client). This explains exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

initialise the Eureka client and fetch the registered apps:

```
List<Application> applications = eurekaClient.getApplications().getRegisteredApplications();

    applications.stream()
            .forEach(application -> {
                application.getInstances().stream()
                        .forEach(instanceInfo -> {
              // get instanceInfo.getHostName() instanceInfo.getPort()
                        });
            });
```